# How to filter JSON in php?

Tags: php, json, filter

i have this JSON

```
[
{"name":"Juan","Sex":"Male","ID":"1100"},{"name":"Maria";"Sex":"Female","ID":"2513"},{"name":"Pedro";"Sex":"Male","ID":"2211"}
]
```

I want to get only those with this ID 2513

```
[
{"name":"Maria";"Sex":"Female","ID":"2513"}
]
```

Comment: Did you find the `json_decode()` function in [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) yet?

Comment: Reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php would be a good start point.

Comment: @Tu I've added an answer for you, hope it helps :)

Comment: here is the solution :) THX! https://3v4l.org/kZrMo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JSON String is **invalid**. First replace all the semicolons `;` with comma `,` and then try using `array_filter()` or any other way e.g `foreach()` with `if` condition etc. I've used the `array_filter()` way, hope it helps :)

```
<?php
$json = '[{"name":"Juan","Sex":"Male","ID":"1100"},{"name":"Maria","Sex":"Female","ID":"2513"},{"name":"Pedro","Sex":"Male","ID":"2211"}]';
$array = json_decode($json,1);
$ID = 2513;
$expected = array_filter($array, function ($var) use ($ID) {
    return ($var['ID'] == $ID);
});
print_r($expected);
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/kZrMo

Answer (score 1):

Use `json_decode()` to convert the JSONString to a PHP array of objects

```
$str = '[{"name":"Juan","Sex":"Male","ID":"1100"},"name":"Maria";"Sex":"Female","ID":"2513"},{"name":"Pedro";"Sex":"Male","ID":"2211"}]';

$arr = json_decode($str);

foreach ( $arr as $obj ){
    if ( $obj->ID == 2513 ) {
        echo $obj->name;
    }
}
```